# Memory leak with Qt SQL and QOCI driver (Oracle OCI driver)

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, driver, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In the following C++ 17 program, different static analyzers show a memory leak when closing and opening the database.

I wrote a minimal reproducible example that show the part where the actual code seems to leak.

Changing the SQL driver seems to reduce the memory leaks detection but there is still some.

Here is the example with the memory leak report after :

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <mcheck.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <QSqlDatabase>

auto getDb() -> QSqlDatabase {
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");

    db.setDatabaseName("db");
    db.setHostName("123.456.789");
    db.setUserName("userName");
    db.setPassword("password");
    db.setPort(1234);
    db.setConnectOptions("OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS=100;OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_MEMORY=0");

    return db;
}

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " ITERATIONS WITH_TRACE USE_FIX" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const long ITERATIONS = std::strtol(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
    const bool TRACE      = std::strtol(argv[2], nullptr, 10) == 1;
    const bool USE_FIX    = std::strtol(argv[3], nullptr, 10) == 1;
    
    QSqlDatabase db = getDb();

    std::cout << "Running test loop of " << ITERATIONS << " iterations ...\n" << std::endl;

    if (TRACE) {
        std::cout << "start mtrace" << std::endl;
        mtrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) { std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl; }

        // Refresh the connection
        if (db.isOpen()) { 
            db.close();
            
            // Possible fix
            if (USE_FIX) {
                QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("db");
                db = getDb();
                
            }
        }

        db.open();
        // End refresh
    }

    if (TRACE) { muntrace(); }
    
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("db");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Dr Memory**

```
~~Dr.M~~ Error #829: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0xffffffffff5ff080-0xffffffffff5ff084 4 byte(s)
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 linux-vdso.so.1!?                  +0x0      (0x00007ffc4f452bcf <linux-vdso.so.1+0xbcf>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 libclntshcore.so.12.1!sLdiGetDate          
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 libclntsh.so.12.1!dbglWriteLogCommon
~~Dr.M~~ # 3 libclntsh.so.12.1!dbgrlWriteAlertDetail
~~Dr.M~~ # 4 libclntsh.so.12.1!dbgrlWriteAlertText
~~Dr.M~~ # 5 libclntsh.so.12.1!nlddwrtlog       
~~Dr.M~~ # 6 libclntsh.so.12.1!nldsadrvfp       
~~Dr.M~~ # 7 libclntsh.so.12.1!nldsfprintf      
~~Dr.M~~ # 8 libclntsh.so.12.1!niqlce1          
~~Dr.M~~ # 9 libclntsh.so.12.1!niotns           
~~Dr.M~~ #10 libclntsh.so.12.1!osncon           
~~Dr.M~~ #11 libclntsh.so.12.1!kpuadef          
~~Dr.M~~ #12 libclntsh.so.12.1!upiini           
~~Dr.M~~ #13 libclntsh.so.12.1!kpuatch          
~~Dr.M~~ #14 libclntsh.so.12.1!OCIServerAttach  
~~Dr.M~~ #15 libqsqloci.so!_init                +0x4e16   (0x00007fd42669b12f <libqsqloci.so+0xb12f>)
~~Dr.M~~ #16 libQt5Sql.so.5!QSqlDatabase::open  +0x30     (0x00007fd428db3ce1 <libQt5Sql.so.5+0x14ce1>)
~~Dr.M~~ #17 main                                [/opt/select/gitlab-runner/francelis/frlis_DbCore/src/MemoryLeakTest.cpp:56]

...

~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS FOUND:
~~Dr.M~~     101 unique,   578 total unaddressable access(es)
~~Dr.M~~     759 unique,  5364 total uninitialized access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
~~Dr.M~~       4 unique,     8 total warning(s)
~~Dr.M~~       2 unique,     2 total,  41616 byte(s) of leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       1 unique,     1 total, 139648 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS IGNORED:
~~Dr.M~~     328 unique,   552 total, 854604 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
~~Dr.M~~          (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
```

**mtrace**

```
= Start
@ /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:(_ZN10QArrayData8allocateEmmm6QFlagsINS_16AllocationOptionEE+0x59)[0x7fa2d5f16fe9] + 0xbb8f20 0x4e
@ /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:(_ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii+0x45)[0x7fa2d5f643a5] + 0xbb90b0 0x20
@ /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:(_ZN10QArrayData8allocateEmmm6QFlagsINS_16AllocationOptionEE+0x59)[0x7fa2d5f16fe9] + 0xbb9020 0x4e
@ /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:(_ZN10QArrayData8allocateEmmm6QFlagsINS_16AllocationOptionEE+0x59)[0x7fa2d5f16fe9] + 0xbb8fd0 0x46
@ /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5:(_ZN10QArrayData8allocateEmmm6QFlagsINS_16AllocationOptionEE+0x59)[0x7fa2d5f16fe9] + 0xbb8ef0 0x20
@ /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so:[0x7fa2d6489c3f] - 0xbb8ef0
@ /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so:[0x7fa2d6489c47] - 0xbb8fd0
...
@ /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1:(nlnvmal+0x1a)[0x7fa2d32d9fda] + 0xbded30 0x38
@ /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1:(nlnvmal+0x1a)[0x7fa2d32d9fda] + 0xbded70 0x5
@ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:[0x7fa2d643b16e] + 0xbe2b10 0x90
@ /lib64/libc.so.6:(__strdup+0x1a)[0x7fa2d506cb8a] + 0xbe2bb0 0x28
@ /lib64/libnss_myhostname.so.2:(_nss_myhostname_gethostbyname4_r+0x1e3)[0x7fa2c6a032b3] - 0xbe2bb0
@ /lib64/libc.so.6:(__resolv_context_put+0x45)[0x7fa2d50f08f5] - 0xbdf320
@ /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1:[0x7fa2d32d948d] - 0xbdf300
...
= End
...
```

**valgrind**

```
==649== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==649== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==649== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==649== Command: bin/MemoryLeakTest 1 0
==649== 
==649== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==649==    at 0xB3AC860: lmmmalloc (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB18EEC5: lmmcis (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB194589: lpmpali (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB19413C: lpmloadpkg (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB17609A: lfvLoadPkg (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB175D45: lfvSetShlMode (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB17573F: lfvini1 (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB175384: lfvinit (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7FB1768: kpummpin (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7A3C6A3: kpuenvcr (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x79F370E: OCIEnvCreate (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x41DDF90: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649== 
==649== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==649==    at 0xB3AC88F: lmmmalloc (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB18EF8B: lmmcis (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB194589: lpmpali (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB19413C: lpmloadpkg (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB17609A: lfvLoadPkg (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB175D45: lfvSetShlMode (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB17573F: lfvini1 (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB175384: lfvinit (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7FB1768: kpummpin (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7A3C6A3: kpuenvcr (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x79F370E: OCIEnvCreate (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x41DDF90: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649== 
==649== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==649==    at 0xB114130: lxgt2u (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB3A0F47: lxgcnvb (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB3996B0: lxgcnv (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x87FD6CA: kpuecs2u (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xA33AADC: OCIErrorGet (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x41DB993: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x41DC0EF: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x41DF071: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x4041CE0: QSqlDatabase::open() (in /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.10.1)
==649==    by 0x402C8E: main (MemoryLeakTest.cpp:56)
==649== 
==649== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==649==    at 0xB1141AD: lxgt2u (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB3A0F47: lxgcnvb (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB3996B0: lxgcnv (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x87FD6CA: kpuecs2u (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xA33AADC: OCIErrorGet (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x41DB993: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x41DC0EF: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x41DF071: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x4041CE0: QSqlDatabase::open() (in /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.10.1)
==649==    by 0x402C8E: main (MemoryLeakTest.cpp:56)
==649== 
==649== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==649==    at 0x8604854: __intel_sse2_strncpy (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0xB176387: lfvpkgname (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7FB1795: kpummpin (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x7A3C6A3: kpuenvcr (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x79F370E: OCIEnvCreate (in /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1)
==649==    by 0x41DDF90: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x41E8712: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqloci.so)
==649==    by 0x4043851: ??? (in /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.10.1)
==649==    by 0x4043D60: QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&) (in /opt/Qt5/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.10.1)
==649==    by 0x4027E8: main (MemoryLeakTest.cpp:28)
...
==649== LEAK SUMMARY:
==649==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 2 blocks
==649==    indirectly lost: 41,488 bytes in 8 blocks
==649==      possibly lost: 139,648 bytes in 3 blocks
==649==    still reachable: 763,863 bytes in 332 blocks
==649==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==649== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==649== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

Even with the `USE_FIX`, memory errors are displayed. How to get rid off those errors ?

Comment: ***How to get rid off those errors ?*** You probably need to file a bug report since the bug is not yours. Although with that said it may be a false positive or an intentional block of memory that is allocated by the driver but never freed.

Comment: This shows compelling evidence of multiple bugs in whatever low level SQL drivers that are being used. This can only be fixed by fixing these low level SQL drivers.

Comment: @drescherjm, further analysis will be led with `pmap` monitoring to confirm these are not false positive. The concrete code base is of course more complex than this example.
@SamVarshavchik We will try to upgrade the drivers to the last version, for now Qt do not want to find the new installed driver :sigh:
Is there a specific way to file a bug report in Oracle ?

Comment: Oracle's OCI library is essence of pure evil. It confuses every memory tracing tool.
Your valgrid trace does not contain necessary information. It just shows usage of un-initialzed memory, which is different case. Also there "always" will be some memory leaks in the valgrind's output. OCI library has some internal structures which are allocated and never de-allocated. Is leak size is constant do not care about it. Try to create test case with many loops and check whether program's memory allocation is growing. Does your leak size depend on number of iterations?

Comment: @ibre5041 I'll focus on observing the leak today (with pmap I think), we extracted this part of the main code base regarding the reports of mem leak analyzers so there is no insurance this was the correct part of the code that leaked considering your statement.

Comment: Ok after monitoring the program process with pmap command `watch -n 1 "pmap ${WATCH_PID} | awk '/total/{print \$2}'"` inside the docker container, the memory used remains the same during the 10k iterations so I'm assuming this program actually do not leak...

Answer (score 0):

Ok after monitoring the program process with pmap command

```bash
watch -n 1 "pmap ${WATCH_PID} | awk '/total/{print \$2}'"
```

inside the docker container running the program, the memory used remains the same during the 10k iterations so I'm assuming this program actually do not leak... *(we failed at targeting the leaking part of the main code)*

Thanks to @ibre5041 comment, all static analyzers memory leak reports are willing to be false positive because of the way Oracle's OCI library is built.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted to close this question.